# edit content on content's language

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, entities

I have a couple of nodes (using node translation) shown on `/en/admin/content`. All the `edit` links point to `/en/node/*/edit` which always has the English language on the URL. This is problematic because for French items the `entityreference` fields show English nodes and not French. In order to solve this I have to manually edit the URL to `/fr/node/*/edit`.

The same applies when initially translating a node. The "add translation" link at `/en/node/*/translate` always starts with `/en/...`. If it'd start with the target language (e.g `/fr/...`) then this problem with the `entityreference` fields would not exist.

Is this a problem of `entityreference` or Drupal? Can it be fixed or configured from somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit links where fixed in `i18n 7.x-1.6`. When I crated this issue I was using `7.x-1.5`.

http://drupal.org/node/1649596